# Dealing with subnet wastage

Tags: networking, subnet

I was given a question. A company needs 3 networks. Given IP address is 176.0.0.0

> Network A: 300 hosts
>
> Network B: 5 hosts
>
> Network C: 75 hosts

So Network A should be having a subnet of /23 and therefore having maximum assignable IP addresses of 510. So there would be a wastage of 210 hosts since 510-300=210.

My question is can I use those 210 IP addresses for Network B and Network C?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Off topic, but I'll answer anyway.

No.  Any assigned network space can only be used by that network.

The only way to use the "wasted" addresses for networks B and C would be to split network A into two or more smaller networks that only use the part of the /23 space that they really need.  That goes against the requirements in the original question, though.

Comment: Thanks. That means those 210 unassigned IP addresses can only be used by Network A for future additional devices, right?